# What is a realistic value for the internal resistance of an ammeter?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, electronics, electrical-engineering

As I understand, ideally an ammeter will have zero resistance as it is connected in series with the circuit and so there will be no potential difference across the device. However, in reality there will be a very small internal resistance associated with an ammeter.

I have recently determined the internal resistance of an ammeter in an experiment at university and obtained a very low value. However, I was wondering what should be realistically expected for the value of internal resistance of an ammeter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is whatever the data sheet says it is. In practice that depends a lot on the measurement range. The shunt resistor needs to be large enough to generate a measurable voltage for the target range for the current.

Here is a data sheet for a Fluke multimeter: the resistance varies from 30 milliohms to 100 Ohms depending on current range.

https://www.grainger.com/ec/pdf/Fluke-Digital-Multimeters-Detailed-Specifications-Sheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Practical answer --- Use another meter set to 'ohms', and plug it into the 'amps' input on the meter in question. Read the result directly. Really, it's that simple....

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on meter (and given meter may have different resistance depending on range) but if you take a look at it's manual it will give you a "burden voltage" which is a function of voltage drop with current - so it's basically resistance (remember that this is not a shunt resistor resistance only other things like protection fuse are also calculated). Usually below 1 [Ohm].
You could test internal meter resistance with other meter but instead of testing resistance directly you should rather use 4 wire Kelvin connection. Multimeters (even those from respected brands) aren't that good for low resistance measurement if you care for accuracy.